# Accessing device native features in cordova webview

Tags: android, ios, cordova, gruntjs, cordova-plugins

I am making a Hybrid Application using cordova-cli. My requirement is that the first page in my application must redirect to a website. The entire data required for the application will be loaded into this website from some other data-sources.

The requirement is to access device native features such as camera, accelerometer etc. from pages on this website.

I am using

```
location.href="http://www.example.com";
```

to open the pages. I need a unified cordova.js file with all the plugins embedded into it.
Currently I am putting the individual plugins into the lib\android\plugin\android and by using the `grunt -f` command from grunt-cli, the cordova.js file recieved for android does not seem to produce expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done I am afraid - because of the way Cordova interacts with the device.

What happens if, using a non-mobile device, you accessed the same website from elsewhere? The website will not know what on earth Cordova is.

Cordova interacts with the native code on the device, so requires this to handle the passing of JS-to-native, and vice-versa.